# Unable to install the wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, service, async-await, windows-xp

I am trying to use async await in visual studio 2010, .net framework 4.0 pointing to windows xp.However I was able to build the project by take hepl from some reference from google by installing async ctp v3. But now I am unable to install the wcf service.Getting following exception.

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get installer types in the C:\Program Files\MenuMate\Menumate Services\MenumateServices.exe assembly.
The inner exception System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException was thrown with the following error message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..

Comment: First step is to catch the `ReflectionTypeLoadException` and inspect the `LoaderExceptions` exception as the error message states. This will tell you what assembly is failing.

Comment: You can't use `async/await` in VS 2010. The *CTP* is a *Community Technology Preview* which means it was only meant for preview, never for production use. Why are you using VS 2010 at all? Why not use a *newer* edition and target .NET 4.0? In VS 2012 and later you can use the actual [Microsoft.Bcl.Async package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) whose latest version is 1.0.168. As for the error, post the *full* exception, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`. You probably forgot to deploy the required dlls. The full exception will probably show which of them are missing

Comment: The community editions of Visual Studio are free and offer more or less the same features as the Pro editions. Instead of trying to get an abandoned preview version to work it would be better to install a Community edition and build the project using the production package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using windows xp, so there is technical limitation we can't update windows and visual studio both.And I think xp doesn't support visual studio 2012.

Comment: You can upgrade Visual Studio just fine. The version of VS isn't related to target OS support, it's the *target .Net runtime* that matters. You can build .NET 4.0 applications, even 2.0 with VS 2017. Your development machine doesn't have to target an unsupported OS like XP anyway to compile .NET applications for it

Comment: Besides, your development machine probably doesn't have 4.0 anymore. All 4.x versions are binary replacements of earlier ones so if you've installed 4.5 or later, it's overwritten the 4.0 runtime. You can use a separate XP machine as a build or test server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks For your support. I am unable to install vs 2012 on Windows XP. It is giving error as "Specified Program require a new version of windows." I am downloading vs 2012 update 5 from the following link.
https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202012&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads

Comment: You don't need to use Windows XP on your development machine to create .NET 4.0 projects. You can't even buy it for quite a few years - it went out of sale when Windows 8 came out 5 years ago

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is an old project. so we have to do it on windows xp and it is a virtual machine.

Comment: Which means you can use Windows 10 just fine. Only the *QA* server has to be Windows XP so you can test the final application. Since you already have Windows XP on a VM you can easily use Windows 10 on another VM or develop on the host (if it's on a dev machine).

Comment: There is no other answer here. As far as the actual question is concerned, you probably forgot to copy all required DLLs. For a real solution, move to a newer VS version and use the release version of Microsoft.Bcl.Async. You can do so on a VM easily. In fact, you could use an Azure VM preconfigured with Visual Studio with a trial account just to see what it's like

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My visual studio 2010 was working fine and i was able to install/unistall service correctly.From the day I am using  async/await this problem is occuring.

Comment: Because you forgot to copy all the DLLs. There are a lot of duplicate questions that show how to fix a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` but you didn't even post the full exception string, as returned by `Exception.ToString()`, only the message. The message explains that you should check the `LoaderExceptions` property. `ToString()` will include it in the result.

Comment: And the actual problem will remain - unsupported NuGet package with an unsupported VS version. Upgrade. I've built async .NET 4.0 applications for Windows XP in the past. I used VS 2012 to do it running on Windows 7, with the RTM version of the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package. It worked on XP just fine